# Idiomatically convert signed to unsigned types if you know that value will be positive

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++20, unsigned-integer, signed-integer

Compare the following code. It's clear from the context that one pointer will always be bigger than the other and the result of `std::distance()` therefore positive. How do I idiomatically convert from signed to unsigned then *without having the compiler complains about narrowing*?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:50,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:50,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:50,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:50,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstring%3E%0A%0Astd::string_view+foo(const+char*+token)%0A%7B%0A++++const+char*+first+%3D+std::strchr(token,+!%27H!%27)%3B%0A++++const+char*+second+%3D+std::strchr(first%2B1,+!%27W!%27)%3B%0A++++return+std::string_view+%7B+first,+std::distance(first,+second)+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++const+char*+hello+%3D+%22Hello+World!!%22%3B%0A++++const+auto+view+%3D+foo(hello)%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25.*s%5Cn%22,+static_cast%3Cint%3E(view.size()),+view.data())%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.66057441253264,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O2+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.35736354273945,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.64263645726055,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.33942558746736,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>
#include <string_view>
#include <cstring>

std::string_view foo(const char* token)
{
    const char* first = std::strchr(token, 'H');
    const char* second = std::strchr(first+1, 'W');
    return std::string_view { first, std::distance(first, second) }; // <-- line in question
}

int main()
{
    const char* hello = "Hello World!";
    const auto view = foo(hello);
    printf("%.*s\n", static_cast<int>(view.size()), view.data());
}
```

Warning:

```
<source>: In function 'std::string_view foo(const char*)':
<source>:10:51: warning: narrowing conversion of 'std::distance<const char*>(first, second)' from 'std::iterator_traits<const char*>::difference_type' {aka 'long int'} to 'std::basic_string_view<char>::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wnarrowing]
   10 |     return std::string_view { first, std::distance(first, second) };
      |      

                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Is there any reason you believe that a simple `static_cast` to a `size_t` will not work?

Comment: Actually the **warning** you quote should actually be an **error**. A narrowing conversion is not allowed in a brace-enclosed c'tor argument list. (It is allowed to be a warning if you used `(...)` instead of `{...}`.)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I guess not if that's the idiomatic way :)

Comment: @AdrianMole It's a warning in gcc 12.2 and it compiles. But I didn't know that

Comment: @AdrianMole The standard only requires a diagnostic message.  A warning is a diagnostic message so it is standard compliant.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get this error is because you are using list initialization an in that context a narrowing conversion is an error.  There are a couple ways to fix this. You can switch from

```
return std::string_view { first, std::distance(first, second) };
```

to

```
return std::string_view(first, std::distance(first, second));
```

which means you no longer have list initialization and narrowing is no longer considered an error or you can be explicit and use `static_cast` like

```
return std::string_view{first, static_cast<std::size_t>(std::distance(first, second))};
```

Comment: But, using either of those fixes, you'll still most likely get a compiler *warning*.

Comment: @AdrianMole You shouldn't and I don't get any here: https://godbolt.org/z/5av9MhsPz

Comment: OK - The second one gives a diagnostic in Static Analysis (not compilation) so I'll accept your point there. But the first gives: *warning C4365: 'argument': conversion from '__int64' to 'const std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>::size_type', signed/unsigned mismatch* with MSVC and a similar message in clang-cl.